# iOS 8 app downloading issue

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode7

Recently I've migrated to Xcode 7 and iOS 9, review team passed my update. My app is compatible with iOS 7.1+. But, unfortunately, all users with iOS with version prior 9.0 cannot download app from app store and iTunes with following issues. In App store (app downloading failure):

[image]

and iTunes (trouble with downloading - cannot find URL on server)

[image]

Has anyone already faced this issue?

Comment: probably the Russian users... I have never seen such error message on my screen.

Comment: @holex - Russian users?! What do u mean?!

Comment: your alert messages look to be in Russian language... no offence, of course, but I have no idea about what your message even says, you might have needed to translate to English maybe...

Comment: @holex - "unable to download app" it says. Fortunately, all I had to do - wait. No offense, of course. Moreover, according to latest opinion poll, our president rate is about 90%!! Wish me luck ;)

Comment: fingers crossed for your candidate. :)

Comment: And for KGB, as usual, of course)

Comment: I see a possible chance to achieve ultimate World-Peace here. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, go to the project settings page.

[Screen shot of settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PFni.png)

Make sure that your Deployment Target setting is set to 8 or less. This setting sets the oldest iOS that your app will be compatible with.

Comment: surely i've got 7.1 minimum sdk. A've shipped already 2 versions of the app - and everything worked fine:(

Answer (score 0):

After 40 hours of waiting, ios 8 and 7 users can now download the app.